# Should I disclose past travels in some form even though I have no proof of travel?

Tags: visas, uk

I am applying for a UK visa under the Global Talent category using the endorsement route.

In this form, it asks me to disclose all my previous international travels.

I have visited a few countries in South America prior to having a passport - there is a treaty that allows it, so it's completely legal. However, there are no stamps about it on my passport and no proof of travel other than pictures.

Should I disclose those in the form even though I have no proof?

Comment: Does it really say *all* or is it eg last 10 years? IIRC the UK typically asks about *all previous visa /entry denials* but actual travel history (as in ‘countries you’ve entered) is not the same

Comment: They ask you for which countries you travelled to and when, they're not asking you to prove any of those trips happened, and they're not asking you which countries you travelled to that you have stamps for. Just follow directions to the letter.

Comment: It says in the last 10 years, which includes those trips.

Comment: My fear is that someone without a clear travel history could do the same and disclose a bunch of trips without doing them. If they get suspicious, I wonder if they would ask for proofs of travels. The best I have are pictures and, in some cases, travel tickets.

Comment: @Wavey_8: If they cannot verify a trip, they will likely ignore it, unless they have positive evidence of deception (for example, you claim that you visited country X on date Y, but some other evidence indicates that you were on the other side of the world on date Y). If they *can* verify a trip, and it's not disclosed, they will be very unhappy with that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are many cases when someone may have travelled to a given country without any trace of it in the passport submitted in a visa application:

- Travel was made on a previous passport, which was since then renewed (because it expired or was lost or stolen)
- Travel was made using some other form of ID (many countries allow citizens of some other countries to use a national ID card rather than a passport, for instance)
- Travel was made on a different passport (for people with multiple citizenships or in some countries, with multiple passports…)
- In many cases, there are no stamps on departure and/or arrival for some combinations
- In many cases even if there should be stamps, there could be many reasons why there wasn’t one (border agent forgot to stamp, border agent just waved you over, border post was closed but crossing was still allowed…)

So the absence of relevant stamps is not a problem. Just answer truthfully about your past travel history. In many cases they will just ignore a lot of it anyway (if they know that that travel does not require a visa at all it does not bring them much useful information), but you should still provide the information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was really helpful! I was never asked to disclose this before.

Answer (score 15):

Yes. Always answer immigration questions honestly to your best ability (although in some circumstances you may want to be clear on your phrasing not to be misinterpreted, mostly to do with employment).

Visas are issued based on a belief you're able to follow the rules that come with them, lying on the application isn't a good place to start, and you'll find the truth a lot easier to remember if you're ever questioned.

Answer (score 10):

In this situation the word "approximately" may be what saves you.  For example, if your Global Talent visa is based on your prowess as an international musical performer, you might say something like

> From 2012 to 2018 I was a member of the band "Corazones Congelados"
> which toured extensively in Chile, Bolivia, Paraguay, and Argentina,
> making approximately 20 international trips.

It's reasonable that a touring musician might not remember the details of their travels, especially if they were living in a region where crossing certain national borders required relatively little in the way of formalities.

Another example, from a friend:

> From 2003 to 2007 I attended MyState University in CityA; I crossed the international border at least 20 times to eat at a popular pizza restaurant in neighboring CityB, but do not have records of exactly when.

Remember, even if you don't have proof of your travels, that doesn't mean it doesn't exist somewhere in a database that your visa examiners have access to.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence. UK is [known to use surveillance a lot](https://www.forbes.com/advisor/business/what-is-five-eyes/).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! This was a great answer.
Where did you friend disclose this in the application? I don't see an open text input field in this part of the application.